# two inputs in one line?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have created a form in react-native which looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const { phoneContainerStyles, loginButtonStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View>
      <Field id="country" name="country" type="select" mode="dropdown" label="Country:" component={FormInput}>
        {
          props.countries && props.countries.map(country => <Picker.Item key={country.code} label={country.name} value={country.code} />)
        }
      </Field>
      <Field id="phone" name="phone" type="phone" label="Phone Number:" component={FormInput} />
      <Button type="submit" title="Login" buttonStyle={loginButtonStyle} onPress={props.handleSubmit(onLogin)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = {
  loginButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#fc4482'
  }
}
```

Here is the FormInput:

```
const FormInput = (props) => {
  const { touched, error } = props.meta || {};
  const { labelStyles, errorStyles } = styles;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={[labelStyles, { display: props.label ? 'flex' : 'none', color: `${(touched && error) ? 'red' : 'black'}` }]}>{props.label}</Text>
      <View style={{ padding: props.inputWrapperPadding }}>
        {returnInput(props)}
        <View>
          <Text style={errorStyles}>{touched ? (error ? error : '') : ''}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const returnInput = (props) => {
  const { touched, error } = props.meta || {};  
  switch (props.type) {
    case 'select':
      .....
    case 'phone':
      return (
        <View>
          <TextBox {...props.input} id={`sel-${props.id}`} value={props.sel} style={styles.phoneSelStyle} />
          <TextBox {...props.input} id={props.id} placeholder={props.placeholder} disabled={props.disabled}
            style={[ styles.textBoxStyle, { borderColor: `${(touched && error) ? 'red' : 'black'}` }]}
            value={props.input.value} onChangeText={value => props.input.onChange(value)} />
        </View>
      );
    default:
      .....
  }
};

const styles = {
  labelStyles: {
    paddingLeft: 16, 
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  errorStyles: {
    color: 'red',
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginRight: 16,
    marginBottom: 8
  },
  pickerStyles: {
    marginLeft: 16, 
    marginRight: 16
  },
  textBoxStyle: {
    marginBottom: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
  }
  phoneSelStyle: {
    width: 50
  }
}
```

Now, I want the two TextInputs below Phone Number label in 1 line.

So, I added this style to View:

```
case 'select':
  .......
case 'phone':
  return (
    <View style={styles.phoneContainerStyles}>
      <TextBox {...props.input} id={`sel-${props.id}`} value={props.sel} style={styles.phoneSelStyle} />
      <TextBox {...props.input} id={props.id} placeholder={props.placeholder} disabled={props.disabled}
        style={[ styles.textBoxStyle, { borderColor: `${(touched && error) ? 'red' : 'black'}` }]}
        value={props.input.value} onChangeText={value => props.input.onChange(value)} />
    </View>
  );
default:
  .......
```

Here is the style:

```
phoneContainerStyles: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
```

Now, If I run my app, then output looks like below:

[image]

I don't know why my textbox gets width = 0. Also, why button comes over the textboxes.

**After following the answer by @Himanshu**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set `display: inline` on the inputs? Or `float:left;`?

Comment: @Granny display inline is not supported in react-native

Comment: Sorry, I am not known with React-native (yet). Was just shooting some options :)

Comment: @Granny ok thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your style like this:

```
//Child view component (<TextBox>) style use flex property
textBoxStyle: {
   flex:2
   borderWidth: 1,
}
phoneSelStyle: {
   //width: 50 don't apply width instead use flex
   flex:8
}

//Parent view style

phoneContainerStyles: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'row'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer is partially true. I mean I get the correct widths of textbox but still Login button is covering the textboxes. I have added the image at the end of the question. Can you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Try setting flex:1 for the parent view of your main login component.

Comment: Tried it. But that gives me wired output. Please take a look at updated question.

Comment: Remove that and give some top margin for the button component.

Comment: That one looks like it works but I can't tap on button.

Comment: Please take a look at new image in question.

Comment: If you have some time then I can give you my project to take a look at it. It's just a startup project so, you won't have to waste much more time.

Comment: won't be able to see right now, you can mail me (himanshudwd765@gmail.com) will try to resolve after my working hour.

Comment: Thanks. I have mailed you a the github link.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. At last found the issue. I don't have to give flex: 1 to phoneContainerStyles. It works....